# Reltionship between "activation function", "link function" and "family"

Tags: generalized-linear-model, link-function

I am trying to get an overall picture associated with the `glm` command in R:

1. It is said that the link function is inverse of activation function. And that the `L{E(response)} = predictor` where `L` is the link function. My understanding is that the activation function can be considered as Cumulative Distribution function.
2. I hope I can make the statement:

   ```
   response ~ Activation_function'(predictor + error)
   ```

   where ' denotes derivative. If that is the case, what does term 'family' associate with in the above statement?
3. It is said that a particular family can have more than one link function. What is the physical significance or need to have multiple link functions? Isn't in that the case the predictor values non-unique across different link functions? Can some one explain this in case of Gaussian family (with link functions: Identity, log and inverse)?

Comment: "it is said" ... by whom, where, in what context? note that "activation function" doesn't seem to be a particularly standard term in the GLM literature (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Link_function) the inverse of the link is called the "mean function")

Comment: Sorry not to have mentioned the reference: page 423, in book "R in A Nutshell". It contains a map of different families and their associated list of link function.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't find that book saying "the activation function is the inverse of the link function" (it may be that I could be looking at a different edition to yours). Can you provide a quote in your question, please, as well as a reference (also in the question)?

Comment: I missed your comment on "activation function" in your first response. As far as that is concerned, please refer to:Christopher M. Bishop
Pattern Recognition and
Machine Learning

Comment: Could not finish editing successfully. "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" page-180, the paragraph below equation 4.3. It says: "In the machine learning literature f( · ) is known as an activation function, whereas its inverse is called a link function in the statistics literature. The decision surfaces correspond to y(x) = constant, so that wTx + w0 = constant and hence the decision surfaces are linear functions of x, even if the function f( ·) is nonlinear. For this reason, the class of models described by (4.3) are called generalized linear models"